# Responsive multirow tiles carousel - is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollable

I need to do following scrollable:

1. 2 rows of tiles
2. Flexible width - there can be 4, 6 and 8 tiles in a row
3. It has to scroll to left and right to show more tiles

I'm trying to do it for long time but I don't know is it even possible? If I have 2 rows of tiles I have to wrap them into div (so it can't be flexible with amount of tiles anymore). When I have no wrapping divs then I have tiles in one row..

Is it even possible? Any ideas?

Firstly I was trying to customize scrollable from jQuery Tools http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.html but now I don't think I can customize it for this purpose. But maybe I can? :)

Comment: Can you post your markup and CSS? Your question isn't overly clear...

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you just want a responsive carousel?

[This is one](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) I use a lot, I've used it for two layer carousels before. Look at [the examples](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/examples/intermediate-carousels.php) here for multiple row carousels.

You might need to be clearer in your question. Perhaps create some kind of graphic or give the code you've got so far.

Comment: Hi, thank you. I know about caroufredsel. It has multirow carousel but please notice it's not responsive... Maybe I'm wrong but it also require to specify amount of tiles to be displayed at once. 

In my case I have 3 cases for different widths - 4, 6 and 8 tiles in a row.. 

Thank you for notice that my question isn't clear, I will edit it.

Comment: Yeah that carousel can be responsive! That's why I use it lol.

Comment: Thanks for reply. On demo Multiple-row carousel version isn't responsive, and I don't see instruction how to make it responsive.. :). I talk only about multirow example, because other types I know they are responsive.

Comment: http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/examples/responsive-carousels.php

Found by googling "responsive caroufredsel"